# SQL Server Partitioning a large table

Tags: sql-server, partitioning

I have a huge table (over 200 000 000 records) which works slowly. Each record has owner and owning department. In fact there are only 2 departments in the table, one owns about 40 000 records another owns over 200 000 000 records.

I wish that users from first department had faster access to their records, so my plan was to partition the table by department. However I've realized that I'm unable to modify queries that run over this table (they are built in the software which is not ours), and each query only selects records by user, not by department.

I wonder would the performance still increase if partition the table by department (because one user could only be in one department), or I need to look for something else.

Please note, that example above is simplified, in fact the table has lots of joins with other smaller tables, lots of indexes etc. Until some time indexes helped us a lot, but currently queries run very slowly.

Comment: Is owner the same thing as the user specified in queries?  Perhaps we can better help if you post the existing table DDL (including indexes) and sample query.  Indexing rather than partitioning alone is usually the way to improve performance.